# Swagger HashMap property type

Tags: dictionary, swagger, openapi

Is there any way to define a HashMap or Generic Object type in the models section?
I have a REST service that returns products and those products can have different options. The options property are basically a HashMap, where the id is the option name and its value is the option value.

Comment: What flavor of Swagger are you using? (jax-rs, play, etc)

Comment: @Eyal : We are using swagger-ui and have the same problem. Do you have a solution or workaround?

Comment: @JanHartung No, we don't have too many maps in our api's ... you might want to subscribe to [this feature request in the swagger issue tracking system.](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/issues/244)

Answer (score 44):

Yes it's possible.

In OpenAPI (fka. Swagger) 2.0 and 3.0, a hashmap is always a `<string, something>` map:

- The key is always a string and do not need to be defined.
- The value type is what you want and is defined with `additionalProperties`.

Let's say you want to describe a `<string, string>` hashmap like this one:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

The corresponding OpenAPI 2.0 definition will be:

```yaml
definitions:
  StringStringMap:
    type: object
    additionalProperties:
      type: string
```

In OpenAPI 3.0 the definition will be:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    StringStringMap:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        type: string
```

A `<string, object>` hashmap like this

```
{
  "key1": {"someData": "data", "someOtherData": true},
  "key2": {"someData": "data2", "someOtherData": false}
}
```

will be defined this way in OpenAPI 2.0:

```yaml
definitions:
  ComplexObject:
    type: object
    properties:
      someData:
        type: string
      someOtherData:
        type: boolean

  StringObjectMap:
    type: object
    additionalProperties:
      $ref: "#/definitions/ComplexObject"
```

and in OpenAPI 3.0:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    ComplexObject:
      type: object
      properties:
        someData:
          type: string
        someOtherData:
          type: boolean

    StringObjectMap:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ComplexObject"
```

I've just covered this in depth in [part 4 of my OpenAPI (fka Swagger tutorial)](http://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-4-advanced-data-modeling/).

The [OpenAPI (fka. Swagger) specification explains briefly this too](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#model-with-mapdictionary-properties).

Comment: This is helpful, and works if the data structure for the values are all of the ComplexObject type. However, I have a scenario where the structure of the values varies depending on the pattern of the key. In JSON Schema, I could express this easily using patternProperties. Any thoughts on how one might express this in OAS/Swagger?

Comment: I'm using swagger 2.0. I want to get <string, List<object>>.How can we get this type of response ?

Comment: Nice tip! However there's a tricky issue, like examples defined in this syntax wouldn't be shown properly, looks like this attribute is just missing from example value. Any clue to work around this?

Comment: @arnaud can we have a hashmap with different key i.e. <integer, someObj>

Comment: Looks great, I stil don't understand how to define `string` as the key type when `$ref` is used as a value (Open API 3, of course). Can you please explain it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was really useful and I upvoted it, but this sentence in the last OAS 3 example confused me endlessly `#/definitions/ComplexObject`. I came to the conclusion that you meant `#/components/schemas/` as the `definitions` keyword belongs in the Swagger 2.0 schema. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. without any value type restriction

```
      definitions:
        dynamicFields:
          type: object
          additionalProperties: {}
```

Example : you can pass any type of value here

```
{
   "dynamicFields" : {
      "accountNo": "aaaaaa3455",
      "customerNo": 123455,
      "isApplicable": true,
      "phoneNo": [
        "38859379384",
        3948399448,
        true
      ]
    }
}
```