# How to map object within object in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

Recently a fellow has recommended Swagger to me to write  my API with...

Now after searching for a while, I haven't found the way to map my JSONs quite easily.

This is how my response looks like:

```
{ 1 : {
        name: "foo", age: 22
      },
  2 : {
        name: "bar", age:14
      },
  3 : {
        name: "boo", age: 26
      },
  4 : {
        name: "far", age: 19
      } 
}
```

So basically I have an object, where the key is an ID, and the value is another object, which has normal key/value pairs.
Now I'm sure someone before me has needed this, but I couldn't find the way to write this.

How would I write this in Swagger?

Thank you for any help / example / referance to another question!

Comment: It is difficult for me to understand your question. Ca you specify your deal with Swagger in your problem?

Comment: I will edit my post with the question, but basically, how would this be written in Swagger? How would I define this response?

Comment: what are you using for java-json conversion? That should handle this.

Comment: Did you updated the question?

Comment: Almost the same question has been answered here (by me): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042885/swagger-hashmap-property-type/36711449#36711449 
Note that hashmap keys are strings.