# describe in swagger where object first field is a distinct string not named

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

If I have an array of objects which are various applications that look for example like this

```
Application Name 1
    _Id: 1
    category: design
    version: xx.xy
Application Name 2
    _Id: 2
    category: spreadsheet
    version: xx.xx
```

etc

How do I describe the first field?

so

I will have an array of $ref: "#/definitions/Application" and the other fields are easy

```
Application:
    type: object
    properties:
        _Id:
            type: integer
        category: 
            type: string
```

etc

But how do I handle the names? ie Application name 1, 2 etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger: map of <string, Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136885/swagger-map-of-string-object) and [Swagger HashMap property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042885/swagger-hashmap-property-type)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
    "items":{
        type: array
        items:{
          properties:{
              "Name":{
                  type:object,
                  properties:{
                    _Id:{
                        type: integer
                    },
                    category: {
                        type: string
                    },
                    version:{
                      type: string  
                    }
                  }

              }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that miss out the name of the application? ie each element of the array has  "name of application 1": { _id: 1, category: "finance"} "name 2": {_id:2, category: "dcvnv"} etc

Comment: you must have a object which contained all array of object right?

Comment: "items": [
   {"Name 1": {
    "_id": 191,
    "version": "2",
    "category": "B" }},
   {"Name 2": {
    "_id": 192,
    "version": "2",
    "category": "C"}}]

Comment: check now i updated my answer