# swagger 3: schema for dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor, openapi

I want to model a schema where response is dictionary of dictionaries:

```
{
  'id1': {
    'type': 'type1',
    'active': true,
  }, 
  'id2': {
    'type': 'type2',
    'active': false,
  },
  ... 
  ... 
}
```

I have defined:

```
components:
  schemas:
    accountData:
      type: object
      required:
        - type
        - active
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
        active:
          type: boolean

    accounts:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        type: object
        properties:
          account-id:
            type: object
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/accountData'
```

Now I want to define '#/components/schemas/accounts' which is a repeating dictionary of '#/components/schemas/account'.

I am very new to OpenApi 3, I am unable to figure out how to do it.

Comment: What have you tried? How did that not work? See if this helps: [Swagger HashMap property type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16042885/113116), [Swagger: map of <string, Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36136885/113116)

Comment: So you have a `<string, Object>` map. Check out the answers to the linked questions in my previous comment. Those answers are for OpenAPI 2.0, so replace `definitions` with `components.schemas` to adjust for the 3.0 syntax.

Comment: @helen I have updated the question. Can you please check if I am doing it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. The schema specified in `additonalProperties` corresponds to the value type in the `<key, value>` dictionary. In your example, the values are `accountData` objects, so you should use:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    ...

    accounts:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/accountData'
```

Comment: Where is the <key> in the accounts schema?

Comment: @ArindamChoudhury: In your example the keys are `'id1'`, `'id2'` etc. In OpenAPI, keys are always strings and are not defined explicitly.

Comment: @Helen, may be you know - how can i do this with java annotations?

Comment: @DanBrandt I don't know, sorry. Consider [asking a new question](/questions/ask?tags=swagger+java) about Java annotations.