# How to specify an unknown number of a parameter in the response Open API

Tags: openapi

I'm trying to model my API using swagger and the Open API 3.0 specification. I have made some schemas and now I'm modeling the response of my endpoints. The problem is that they return something like this:

```json
[
 {
  "name": "this attribute is always here"
  "type1": { "description": "this maybe appear or not"  },
  "type2": { "description": "this maybe appear or not"  },
  ...
  "typeN": { "description": "N is not a fixed number, it may range from 0 to another positive integer"  },
 }
]
```

I know how to model the array and the object (with the `name` property). The problem comes when I have to model the `typeX` properties, I do not know how to specify that they are optional and the number of ocurrences is variable. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This object is basically a string-to-object [dictionary/hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16042885/113116) with an extra `name` property. Fixed properties are defined in `properties`, and the dictionary part can be defined using either `patternProperties` (in OpenAPI 3.1) or `additionalProperties` (in OpenAPI 3.0 and 2.0).

#### OpenAPI 3.1

In OAS 3.1 your object can be defined as follows. Since the optional property names all follow the `typeX` format, the schema uses `patternProperties` to define the regex for the property names.

```yaml
MyObject:
  type: object
  required: [name]
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
  patternProperties:  # <-- This part defines the "typeX" properties
    ^type\d+$:        # <-- Property name regex
      type: object    # <-- Property value
      properties:
        description:
          type: string
  additionalProperties: false  # No other properties other than "name" and "typeX"
```

#### OpenAPI 3.0 and 2.0

In earlier OAS versions, you use `additionalProperties` to define "may have extra properties with <such> values", but there's no way to define the format of those property names. You can however mention the property name format in the schema description and also add a schema `example` for documentation purposes.

```yaml
MyObject:
  type: object
  description: >-
    In addition to the `name` property, this object may have an arbitrary
    number of properties named `typeX` where X is a positive integer.
  required: [name]
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
  additionalProperties:
    # This part defines the *value* of the typeX properties
    type: object
    properties:
      description:
        type: string

  # Optional schema example
  name: something
  type1:
    description: ....
  type2:
    description: ....
```